# Inverse image of a subset of the codomain with elements without corresponding elements in domain

Tags: functions

I consider the function $f(x) = x^2 : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ whose image is $[0, + \infty)$. For the sake of simplicity: domain $D = \mathbb{R}$, codomain $C = \mathbb{R}$.

If I consider $A = [-25, 25]$ subset of the codomain $C$, this subset contains elements $[-25, 0)$ which don't have a corresponding element in the domain $D$. In this case is it possible to evaluate the inverse image of $A$? I tried to do it in this way.

According to the definition of the inverse image:

$$
f^{-1}(A) = \lbrace x \in D : f(x) \in A \rbrace
$$

$$
f^{-1}(A) = f^{-1}([0, 25]) = \lbrace x \in [-5, 5] \rbrace
$$

Is it correct?

---

EDIT: the Mathematica software gave me the same result I wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A=[-25,25]$ is not a subset of the $f$'s **range** $[0,\infty),$ so $A$ does not have a **preimage** under $f.$

$f$'s range (let's call it $R$) is a subset of $f$'s codomain, and $R$'s preimage is $f$'s domain.

Comment: Hello @RyanG is the range the image of the function right?

Comment: "Range" and "image" are synonyms. [The wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)).

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation