# Is it proper to speak of the inverse image of a set containing elements not in the image of the mapping?

Tags: continuity, definition, differential-topology, inverse

This may be a duplicate of [Inverse image of a subset of the codomain with elements without corresponding elements in domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4260638/342834)
, but the answer given seems to contradict what is intended by CH Edwards in his Advanced Calculus of Several Variables.

I shall frame the question using the following example.

Let there be a mapping $\vec{r}:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{3}$ defined by $\vec{r}\left(\mathbf{R}\right)=\left\{ x,y,1\right\} $ with $\mathbf{R}=\left\{ x,y\right\} ,$ and let $\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}\left(\vec{r}\left(\mathbf{R}\right)\right)\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$ be an open ball of radius $\epsilon>0$ centered on some specific
$\vec{r}\left(\mathbf{R}\right).$

**Is it proper to call $\vec{r}^{-1}\left(\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}\left(\vec{r}\left(\mathbf{R}\right)\right)\right)$
the inverse image of $\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}\left(\vec{r}\left(\mathbf{R}\right)\right)?$**

I am specifically interested in those points $\left\{ x,y,z\right\} =\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}\left(\vec{r}\left(\mathbf{R}\right)\right)$
for which $z\ne1.$ That is, those points not in the image of $\vec{r}.$

The following abbreviated except from Edwards's book is the reason I ask:

> Theorem 8.2 The mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is continuous
> if and only if, given any open set $\mathcal{U}\subset\mathbb{R}^{m},$
> the inverse image $f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{U}\right)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}.$
> $\dots$

> PROOF The inverse image $f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{U}\right)$ is the set
> of points in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that map under $f$ into $\mathcal{U},$
> that is,
> $$
> f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{U}\right)=\left\{ \mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:f\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\in\mathcal{U}\right\} .
> $$

> We prove the "only if" part of the Theorem, and leave the converse as Exercise 8.4.

> Suppose $f$ is continuous. If $\mathcal{U}\subset\mathbb{R}^{m}$
> is open, and $\mathbf{a}\in f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{U}\right),$ then
> there exists an open ball $\mathcal{B}_{r}\left(f\left(\mathbf{a}\right)\right)\subset\mathcal{U}.$
> Since $f$ is continuous, there exists an open ball $\mathcal{B}_{\delta}\left(\mathbf{a}\right)$
> such that $f\left(\mathcal{B}_{\delta}\left(\mathbf{a}\right)\right)\subset\mathcal{B}_{r}\left(f\left(\mathbf{a}\right)\right)\subset\mathcal{U}.$
> Hence $\mathcal{B}_{\delta}\left(\mathbf{a}\right)\subset f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{U}\right);$
> this shows that $f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{U}\right)$ is open.

Comment: Yes, for any function $f$ and any subset $S$ of the codomain of $f$, we do call $f^{-1}(S)$ the inverse image of $S$ regardless of whether some (or all) points of $S$ are not in the range of $f$.

Comment: $f^{-1}S=\{x:f(x)\in S\}$ regardless of what $S$ is. E.g. in the topological definition of continuity: $f:A\to B$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}S$ is open in $A$ whenever $S$ is open in $B$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet The problem with the latter part is that Edwards states your definition as a theorem, and defines continuity as the limit and the value of  $f$ existing and equaling one another everywhere on the domain.

Comment: From what I read in your abbreviated excerpt, the definition of $f^{-1} S$ given in the comment of @DanielWainfleet agrees exactly with the definition of $f^{-1}(\mathcal U)$ given in your second highlighted portion of that excerpt.

Comment: @LeeMosher I was referring to the definition of continuity.  The theorem 8.2 of Edwards is the definition of continuity used by others.

Comment: Okay, then it looks like your question is answered?

Comment: @LeeMosher Not in a way that I can check off.  It would be nice to have a second authoritative source.  Edwards defines inverse image in one sentence of a proof without giving any examples.

Comment: Okay, so I'll just say that this is the universal definition of the inverse image of a subset of $Y$ with respect to any function $X \mapsto Y$, regardless of whether that subset is contained in the image of the function. Check **any** topology book, that's what you'll find.

Comment: @LeeMosher I don't doubt that in the least bit.  If someone posts that as an answer with one, or preferably two authoritative references, I will happily accept it.  In lieu of that, I will have to set this aside until I have time to examine other sources for myself.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image